# How to stop all progs ran in parallel from bash-script when it stopped by ctrl+c

Tags: bash

```
#! /bin/bash
make clean
make
port_number=8888
(./s $port_number) & 
(./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number) &
(./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number) &
```

s and c are simple tcp server and client. When clients did all and stopped server still running. But when i stop script by Ctrl+C server remained in memory and i need to kill it manually. How to kill it with script?

added:

good point to trapping from accepted answer + using wait bring it to work.

worked one:

```
#! /bin/bash

make clean
make
port_number=8888
(./s $port_number) &
s_pid=$!
(./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number) &
(./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number) &

trap "{ kill -SIGKILL $s_pid ; exit 0; }" SIGINT
wait
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the pids of the proccesses:

```
#! /bin/bash
make clean
make
port_number=8888
./s $port_number & 
s_pid=$!
./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number &
./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number &
```

and trapping the SIGINT signal (should be at the end of the script)

```
trap "{ kill -SIGKILL $s_pid ; exit 0; }" SIGINT
```

you could save the pid to a file and parametrize the script so you could say

```
$ actions start
```

and

```
$ actions stop
```

something like

```
#! /bin/bash
pidfile="server.pid"

start_it(){
  echo "Starting ..."
  make clean
  make
  port_number=8888
  (./s $port_number) & 
  # write pid-file
  echo $! > $pidfile
  (./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number) &
  (./c 127.0.0.1 $port_number) &
}

stop_it(){
  read -r pid < $pidfile
  kill $pid
  echo "Stopped."
}

case "$1" in
  start)
  start_it
  exit 0
  ;;
  stop)
  stop_it
  exit 0
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

.. if this is not a bit too much :)

Comment: it doesnt work, and doesnt trap even if write **trap '' SIGINT** before calling parallel progs. May be calling in parallel causes some problems for trap?

Comment: The trap call should be at the end of the script. 
But if the script 'exits' e.g. you are returned to the shell after execution, the pid should be saved to a file. If I understand correctly, the ./c (clients) exit on their own?

Comment: yes, on their own, in memory only ./s. I think what script already ended when i press Ctrl+C, and signal send to another entity. I dont really know what **(./s $port_number) &** do, i think () generate subshell and subshell get signal not the main script((

Comment: Thanks alot man. But your suggestion about trap was really helpful and with addition of **wait** healed it)))

Answer (score 0):

Like this, for instance:

```
kill $(jobs -p)
```